# Find which part of a multiple regex gave a match

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a multiple regex which combines thousands of different regexes e.g `r"reg1|reg2|..."`.

I'd like to know which  one of the regexes gave a match in `re.search(r"reg1|reg2|...", text)`, and I cannot figure how to do it since `` `re.search(r"reg1|reg2|...", text).re.pattern `` gives the whole regex.

For example, if my regex is `r"foo[0-9]|bar"`, my pattern `"foo1"`, I'd like to get as an answer `"foo[0-9]`.

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap each sub-regexp in `()`. After the match, you can go through all the groups in the matcher (`match.group(index)`). The non-empty group will be the one that matched.

Comment: I cannot do this since python's re only accepts 100 named groups

Comment: Even better, [`MatchObject.lastindex`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.lastindex) will hand you the index of the last group that matched.

Comment: same problem, my regex would end in having more than a hundred named groups, `re` cannot handle that

Comment: Build several patterns with 100 elements each and then try to match each in turn.

Comment: I'd like to know whether there is a cleverer way to do this, not to mention the enormous downtime it implies to do this

Comment: Alternatively, group N patterns in a kind of super group (i.e. `(reg1|reg2|reg3)|(reg4|...)`). When you have a match, in one of those, match a second time but use a new pattern that groups each individial regexp.

Comment: @Raphael_LK: There are other ways (implement your own regexp engine, for example) but I doubt there is one that is faster and more "clever"

Comment: Ok Aaron, I'm going to give a try to your solution

Answer (score 0):

You could put each possible regex into a list, then checking them in series, as this would be faster than one very large regex, and allow you to figure out which matched as you need to:

```
mystring = "Some string you're searching in."
regs = ['reg1', 'reg2', 'reg3', ...]
matching_reg = None
for reg in regs:
    match = re.search(reg, mystring)
    if match:
        matching_reg = reg
        break
```

After that, `match` and `matching_reg` will both be `None` if no match was found. If a match was found, `match` will contain the regex result and `matching_reg` will contain the regex search string from `regs` that matched.

Note that `break` is used to stop attempting to match as soon as a match is found.

Comment: Ah I thought that checking them in series would, on the contrary, be slower than checking only one big regex. I find this quite surprising, do you have any benchmark to support this ?

Comment: It took a bit to test. I found that compared to the approach of having several sets of 99 groups each, the series approach is slightly (~5%) faster if you're pre-compiling the regexes, but significantly slower if not. Further, if you don't actually need to know which of the regexes matched, but rather only which literal string section matched, (E.g. knowing just that `ace` was the matched term is okay instead of knowing `[ab][cd][ef]` was the matching regex), then the 99-per version is definitely faster by about 20%.

Comment: Thanks for this in depth comment. This precompiling thing is funny, since I read somewhere on SO that either explicitly stated or not, Python compile the regex before looking for a match

Comment: You heard correctly, Python's re module does indeed compile before searching, and will reuse rather than recompile when you make the same search again. However, according to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile), re only saves a limited number of compiled expressions automatically. When dealing with 1000+, it will likely have to recompile on the fly as each is called.